# Can an unused typedef or struct definition ever cause a change in behavior within a C program?

Tags: c, compilation, undefined-behavior

Suppose one has code along the lines of the following:

```
struct Container1
{
   int data;
};

typedef int Container2;

int main ()
{
   // code that does stuff but never
   // utilizes any of the 'Container'
   // types.
}
```

The this example neither Container1 nor Container2 are being used. I should clarify this is a generic example. The question I have is whether there are ANY circumstances in either known 'undefined behavior' from specific compilers *or* a clause of the C standard *or* a blatant compiler bug that would result in the presence of an unused struct having a distinct change to a compiled program's behavior.

Warnings or even blatant compilation errors should be ignored in this circumstance a this is asking whether a compiled executable could have distinctly different results. Compiler warnings/errors that prevent a build from finishing don't fall into that category.

My expectation is that there is a hard answer of ***NO***, but I believe people have mentioned in passing in the past times that they've seen unusual bugs due to removing or changing the definition of or even changing the name of a completely 100% unused typedef or struct definition. I do not have such examples, and so I will say that I take the claims with a grain of salt and a bit of curiosity on why/how that might occur.

Comment: Why do you ask? Do you have some specific case of a compiler producing strange output depending on if you add or remove these lines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, in theory. Consider this code:

```
int a, b;
printf("%d\n", &a+1 == &b);
```

Per C 2018 6.5.9 6, `&a+1 == &b` is true if and only if `b` **happens** to immediately follow `a` in the address space. This is defined behavior, but the behavior of the C implementation may cause the result to be either 0 or 1.

Now suppose the C implementation manages its identifiers through some fancy data structure. It reads `a` and remembers information about it, remembers `b` and remembers information about it, and so on. Later, when it is assigning storage to objects, it reads from its database of identifiers. In the absence of additional constraints, such as size and alignment influencing how it allocates storage, it may just allocate storage in whatever order the database happens to produce the identifiers when stepping through the database to get them.

It is conceivable that simply changing what identifiers are in the database may change the order in which others are produced when read back from the database. Thus, introducing a new type name could change the order, resulting in `b` following `a` in memory when it did not without the new name.

In other words, the behavior here, regarding how names are managed and how storage is allocated is, at least in part, uncontrolled—it is not engineered to be one specific way or another. And therefore it could change based on essentially irrelevant things.

Comment: Note that both gcc and clang, given something `int a,b; void test(int *p) { if (p==&a+1) *p=1; }`, will sometimes assume that the store will never affect `b`, even in cases where they have in fact placed `a` and `b` at consecutive address, and the caller might legitimately have passed the address of `b`.

Answer (score 3):

Short answer is **no**. And the compiler should produce identical (or equivalent) object code with and without an unused struct.

Every seasoned engineer has got a story about some weird bug as a result of changing something innocuous. But cases like that - it's because of some other bug, not from an unused data type.

Comment: @Typhon - rather than present some hypotheticals that would be really extreme and can't casually happen. Let me just assure you that removing dead code is a good thing.  Otherwise if the culture of your software team is to "never change something not broken" and doesn't believe in cleaning up dead code, it would be somewhat sad.  I assume you and your **test the code** that you build, right?

Comment: selbie, while I totally agree with what you state, could you support it with quotes from standard? I ask because that is what I am not so good at finding...

Comment: @Yunnosch - The standard docs for C and C++ rarely, if ever, define how object code is generated. Nor do such texts discuss how optimizations work. The standards discuss expected program behavior but nothing likely exists to define the behavior of an unused struct.

Comment: @Typhon - Please do not take offense to my comment. My presumption was that you wanted to remove some dead code, but someone you trusted was discouraging that.  The fact that you are asking such questions shows your commitment to getting to an expert level sooner than later.

Comment: @selbie I would like a specific example too, as well, because I'm really curious. Since you write _"Every seasoned engineer has got a story about some weird bug as a result of changing something innocuous" I suppose you refere to some real life scenario, don't you?

Comment: I've tried to figure out scenariosin which removing 100% unused types could change a program's behavior, and I actually found a really extreme scenario that _fit the requirements_. But that's something so weird that someone has to do this on purpose! If we talk about unused local variables declarations removal it's different: I personally have some true and sad stories of crashes and strange behaviors.

Answer (score 3):

> The question I have is whether there are ANY circumstances in either known 'undefined behavior' from specific compilers or a clause of the C standard or a blatant compiler bug that would result in the presence of an unused struct having a distinct change to a compiled program's behavior

Only if those identifiers `Container1` and `Container2` collide with other identifiers elsewhere in the program.

But it is always possible to come up with various more or less artificial scenarios that would be exceptions to this:

- There's the case where you have syntax errors in some header file included before these definitions, and the definitions somehow fixed the error. Example:

  foo.h

  ```
  typedef
  ```

  foo.c

  ```
  #include "foo.h"

  struct Container1 
  {
     int data;
  };

  int x;
  ```

  If the struct is removed, `x` will become a typedef for `int`. Otherwise `x` is a variable of type `int`.
- Removing the struct will obviously affect things like the `__LINE__` macro.

  ```
  #include <stdio.h>

  struct Container1
  {
     int data;
  };

  int main()
  {
    printf("%s", &"hello world"[__LINE__]); 
  }
  ```

  Output: `d`

  ```
  #include <stdio.h>

  int main()
  {
    printf("%s", &"hello world"[__LINE__]);
  }
  ```

  Output: `world`
- C90 only guaranteed up to 6 unique characters of an external identifier. So if you would have some code elsewhere with another struct called `Container2` and some external identifier like `extern struct Container2`, then the presence/absence of `Container1` struct definition might have given different results, since only the `Contai` part of the identifier would have to be unique.
- And so on... C is a complex language, filled with of strange loopholes and special cases.

Answer (score 0):

> a blatant compiler bug

If your compiler is buggy then anything can happen. For example the bug in the compiler could be that if a typedef using the name "Container2" is defined then it inserts a "rm -rf /" into your main function.

See, now the unused typedef has an effect.

Comment: If you are asking for specific compiler bugs then you beter mention what compiler and version you are using. Otherwise the question is more than useless.